# How do I shorten this if possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Well, here's my code

```
import time

import random

Dice = input("Would you like to roll the dice?(y/n)")

if Dice == "y":

    roll = random.randint(1,6)

    print("You have rolled a", roll)

    again = input("Would you like to roll again?(y/n)")

    while again == "y":

        roll2 = random.randint(1,6)

        print("You have rolled a", roll2)

        again = input("Roll again?(y/n)")

    if again == "n":

        time.sleep(1)

        print("Goodbye")



else:

    time.sleep(1)

    print("Goodbye")
```

If you could help, that'd be great!

Comment: This is not the way to ask a question; asking people to read your code, guess what it should do and do your work for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ive worked on this fir about a week, im thirteen years old, and I dont know how on earth to shorten this.

Comment: You could remove the blank lines (partially a joke, partially serious. Some vertical white space between major sections of code helps readability. Every other line blank is annoying).

Comment: Why do you want to shorten it, specifically?

Comment: My teacher has said this code could be shortened and has challenged me to do it.

Comment: you could use `sleep()/print` only once - at the end but without `else` and you get the same result.

Comment: Don't double-space your code.

Comment: some hints: there is same code repeated twice.. focus on this
why both 'again' and 'Dice'? in fact it holds the same user decision...

Comment: Im, well not a great programmer yet. So please dont judge too harshly, plus, im thirteen

Comment: Thirteen? If you were seven, then I would say "Hmmm, OK it's just a kid"... but thirteen years old and asking others to do his homework and using his young age as an excuse? OMG!

Answer (score 4):

```
import random
while input('RTD? (y/n) ') == 'y': print('Rolled {}.'.format(random.randint(1, 6)))
```

Comment: I love it. King of shortening.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like doing someones homework. But here you go, a shortened version of your code (untested).

```
import time
import random

dice = input("Would you like to roll the dice?(y/n)")

while dice == "y":
    print( "You have rolled a %s" % (random.randint(1,6)))
    dice = input("would you like to roll again?(y/n)")

time.sleep(1)
print("Goodbye")
```

Comment: Wow, This is really helpful, I actually didnt think of this

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import random

while input("Would you like to roll the dice? (y/n) ") == 'y':
    roll = random.randint(1,6)
    print("You have rolled a", roll)

print("Goodbye")
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Andreas: the bulk is three lines of code. It hardly needs explaining, even for a beginner.

Comment: Have you even looked at the post I linked?

Comment: @Andreas: I follow the principle behind the most voted and the accepted answers: "for certain questions they *are* enough" and "often a short snippet of code really is all that is needed".

Answer (score 0):

Use while loop:

```
import time

import random

Dice = raw_input("Would you like to roll the dice?(y/n)")
while Dice.lower() == "y":
    roll = random.randint(1, 6)
    print("You have rolled a ", roll)
    Dice = raw_input("Would you like to roll again?(y/n)")
time.sleep(1)
print("Goodbye")
```